# How to connect to MySQL using SSL on symfony/doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I am trying to connect to MySQL that has SSL enabled.
I am using Symfony2 framework with Doctrine.

In plain PHP, I can achieve this with

```
$link = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1:3306","test","testpass",true,MYSQL_CLIENT_SSL);
```

Does anyone know how I can do this in symfony/doctrine?
What is the correct doctrine configuration in config.yml?

**UPDATE:**

Maybe my question "What is the correct doctrine configuration in config.yml?" is wrong.
So, how do I go about doing this? Where should I start?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found the answer after a long search and with the help from people from doctrine chat room.

This is the dbal configuration that works on PHP > 5.3.7 
It uses three PDO Constants which are not available to PHP prior to 5.3.7

In standard PDO connection:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;database=dbname", "user1", "password1",
    array(
        1010 => '/path/to/certs/priv_key.pem',
        1011 => '/path/to/certs/pub_cert.pem',
        1012 => '/path/to/certs/ca_cert.pem',
    )
);
```

If trying the above code gives you an error, it is possible that your PHP version is < 5.3.7 then you are unlikely to be able to use PDO with SSL.

Now the solution to the DBAL configuration in config.yml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   %database_driver%
                host:     %database_host%
                port:     %database_port%
                dbname:   %database_name%
                password: %database_password%
                charset:  UTF8
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                options:
                    1010 : %priv_key% 
                    1011 : %pub_cert% 
                    1012 : %ca_cert%

            default2: # second connection ...

    orm:
        # orm configuration here ....
```

Hope this helps anyone who are trying to connect using SSL. As a matter of fact, it is recommended to connect using SSL for all your database connection, if it is possible to do so.

Comment: Right answer ! But, don't know where I should place all these *.pem and to what paths should look like..

Answer (score 8):

Just wanted to point out that the integer values of the following **SSL attribute constants** are as follows in PHP 5.4.16:

```
PDO:MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY: 1007
PDO:MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT: 1008
PDO:MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: 1009
```

They may vary from one version to another, `so best to check these values before plugging them into the DBAL confiugration.`

Comment: More info on  constants is  described in the docs http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants