# Secure Propel connection, remote MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, propel

Is it possible to configure Propel to use SSL connection with remote MySQL server?

I found the same question with Doctrine, but it isn't answered either: [How to connect to MySQL using SSL on symfony/doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600028/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-ssl-on-symfony-doctrine)

Comment: I very much need the answer to this question myself. Google doesn't seem to have any results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [connection options](http://propelorm.org/reference/runtime-configuration.html#options) to set [PDO SSL attributes](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#pdo-mysql.constants).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for the runtime config file:

```
$serviceContainer = Propel::getServiceContainer();
$serviceContainer->setAdapterClass($db_name, 'mysql');
$manager = new ConnectionManagerSingle();
$manager->setConfiguration(array(
    'dsn' => 'mysql:host=' . $db_host . ';dbname=' . $db_name,
    'user' => $db_username,
    'password' => $db_password,
    'options' => [
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => '/etc/mysql/client-key.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => '/etc/mysql/client-cert.pem',
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/etc/mysql/ca-cert.pem']
));
$serviceContainer->setConnectionManager('mydb', $manager);
```

And here's an example for the propel config file:

```
propel:
    database:
        connections:
            devServer:
                adapter: mysql
                classname: Propel\Runtime\Connection\DebugPDO
                dsn: mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb
                user: jomedia
                password: mypassword
                options:
                     1010 : /etc/mysql-certs/client-key.pem
                     1011 : /etc/mysql-certs/client-cert.pem
                     1012 : /etc/mysql-certs/ca-cert.pem
```