# Use PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA with Propel ORM

Tags: php, ssl-certificate, propel2

I'm trying to reverse engineer a database with Propel [`reverse`](http://propelorm.org/documentation/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html) command. The database I'm trying to connect to requires a SSL certificate, this is how I connect to it in my application:

```
new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
    'root', '', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => '/path/ssl-cert.crt'
);
```

My Propel config file:

```
propel:
  database:
    connections:
      blog:
        adapter: mysql
        classname: Propel\Runtime\Connection\ConnectionWrapper
        dsn: "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog"
    user: root
    password:
    options:
      PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA: /path/ssl-cert.crt
```

I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Unrecognized option "PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA" under "propel.database.connections.gateway.options"
```

I read this post: [Secure Propel connection, remote MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122558/secure-propel-connection-remote-mysql), the first answer link to an old version of Propel, and I also tried the alternative answer, replacing `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` by its integer value. Nothing worked, has anyone had this problem before? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that only `ATTR_PERSISTENT` option is supported at the moment: [PropelConfiguration](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/master/src/Propel/Common/Config/PropelConfiguration.php#L121)

It should be fairly easy to fork it and patch with something like:

```
->arrayNode('options')
    ->children()
        ->booleanNode('ATTR_PERSISTENT')->defaultFalse()->end()
        ->scalarNode('PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA')->end()
    ->end()
->end()
```

I would recommend to add this scalar node directly in your `vendor/propel/propel/src/Propel/Common/Config/PropelConfiguration.php` and check if there are any hidden bugs or missing functionality.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Since there seems to be a few more options missing in Propel, I might go with a custom solution. However your answer provides a good pointer toward a solution.